# PHP PDO ODBC MSSQL connection

Tags: php, sql-server, iis, pdo, odbc

I've installed PHP on IIS7 following the official PHP documentation and it succeed. I can run PHP files and my site is OK.
But I can't connect to my database on MSSQL with PDO and ODBC driver. I've set my php.ini carefuly and I think all is good. Morever I also think ODBC is native on Windows and PDO is included in latest PHP builds (mine is 5.5.36).

So here's my connection code :

```
define("UID", 'uid');
define("PWD", 'pwd');
define("DSN", 'odbc:decheterie');
// where 'decheterie' is the dataSource set in the ODBC Connection Manager

try {
    $pdo = new PDO(DSN, UID, PWD);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die("Error! ".$e->getMessage());
}
```

The error I get is :

> Error! Could not find driver

If I run a `php -m` I can see that PDO and ODBC modules are correctly loaded.
But a `PDO::getAvailableDrivers()` returns an empty array and it can be verified within the `phpinfo()` which displays 'no value' in the 'PDO drivers' section.

I've read a lot of posts and articles and each time a response is valided as 'problem solving' it's already good in my config.

If someone can help it will be blessed ;)

Comment: php  -m is CLI php, which can/will have an entirely different .ini file than SAPI php (embedded in webserver). if you're running that code under a webserver, then you need to check phpinfo(), because the cli output is pretty much useless. and even if PDO is installed, you still need the specific DB drivers, eg. pdo-mysql.

Comment: Have you tried enabling `php_pdo_sqlsrv_*.dll` in modules in IIS management console?

Comment: Thanks for the info Marc it's so important to test with the right procedure. php_pdo_odbc.dll in ON even if it should be built in with Windows. I've downloaded and referenced the php_pdo_sqlsrv_*.dll and it works fine! Thanks Gofr1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

The answer is in the above comments. You need to DL the php_pdo_sqlsrv_*.dll

in your PHP /ext folder and references it as an extension in your php.ini

The '*' is for the PHP version everything is well described in the 
MSDN doc [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc296170%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Thanks

Comment: It doesn't use ODBC directly, rather use sqlsrv dll than ODBC itself